# Android AES Encryption Error Pad Block Corrupted

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have 3 classes:

1. AESCrypt
2. ChooseMasterPasswordActivity
3. UnlockPocketActivity

I sucessfully add data to SQLite database, but I have problem with decrypting data from database.

I get this error:

```
 W/System.err(1034): javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted.
```

In ChooseMasterPasswordActivity class I use this code to add encrypted text to SQLite database.

```
String masterKey, encryptedMPW;
        masterKey = tvPassword.getText().toString();

        AESCrypt aes = new AESCrypt();
        encryptedMPW =  aes.encrypt(masterKey);

        user = new User(null, encryptedMPW);
        userDao.insert(user);
```

In class UnlockPocketActivity I have method createMasterPassword() with this code:

```
private void checkMasterPassword() throws Exception {

    String pw = tvUnlockMPW.getText().toString();
    String decryptedMPW;

    AESCrypt aes = new AESCrypt();

    decryptedMPW = aes.decrypt(map.get("MPW").toString());



    if (pw.equals(decryptedMPW)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(UnlockPocketActivity.this,
                MainListActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pogresna sifra...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I used this code for clas AESCrypt:

public class AESCrypt {

```
private final Cipher cipher;
private final SecretKeySpec key;
private AlgorithmParameterSpec spec;
private String encryptedText, decryptedText;
private String password = "PASSWORD";

public AESCrypt() throws Exception {

    // hash password with SHA-256 and crop the output to 128-bit for key
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);

    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    spec = getIV();
    }

public AlgorithmParameterSpec getIV() {
    AlgorithmParameterSpec ivspec;
    byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
    ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    return ivspec;
    }

public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {      
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
    encryptedText = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encryptedText;
}

public String decrypt(String cryptedText) throws Exception {
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(cryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
    decryptedText = new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
    return decryptedText;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to initialize your initialization vector with `SecureRandom()` which produce different data with each call.

```
byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
```

The initialization vector needs to be the same at encrypt and decrypt. Save the initialization vector together with the encrypted data, or find a way to produce it so you get the same at encrypt and decrypt. It does not need to be secret, but it ought to be different with each new thing you encrypt.